# Linux wireless: ACK implementation

Tags: linux, driver, wireless, wifi

I have been studying the Linux wireless 802.11 driver, and this question popped up:

Assuming STA A transmits a normal data packet to STA B. 
Based on the 802.11 standard, STA B will send an ACK if it successfully receives the packet from STA A. Meanwhile STA A will switch to receive state in order to receive the ACK from STA B.

My question is:

Where is the code that controls the switching from tx to rx for ACK reception at STA A? 
Is it done by the hardware, or the driver?

Really appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, ACK needs to be send in SIFS standard See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Interframe_Space). The actual value of SIFS varies from protocol to protocol (eg., 802.11b its just 10uS similar can be seen in above shared link).

To technically one has to receive the packet and send ack in 10uS. Doing this in software is possible but its not encouraged because this hard time dependency. Hence generally 802.11 ACKs are generated by the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer from some colleagues implementing 80211: 
ACK is handled by hardware, similarly for some other lower-MAC related functions that has strict timing requirement.